# how can I show that $\overline A + \overline B = \overline{A+B}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Example where closure of $A+B$ is different from sum of closures of $A$ and $B$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60452/example-where-closure-of-ab-is-different-from-sum-of-closures-of-a-and-b)
>   [need one counter example for sum of two closed set need not be closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137431/need-one-counter-example-for-sum-of-two-closed-set-need-not-be-closed)

Given $A$ and $B$ two non empty set in $\mathbb R$ with $A$ bounded
how can I show that $$\overline A + \overline B = \overline{A+B}$$

I have no idea how to approach this question.

Comment: What does $\bar{A}$ denote? Does it denote closure (or) complement? And I assume $C+D$ stands for $\{x+y: x \in C \text{ and }y \in D\}$.

Comment: Not every question about sets has to do with set theory.

Comment: @Marvis $\overline A$ is the closure

Comment: Equality of sets can be viewed as two inclusions.  Can you do one of the inclusions: $\overline A + \overline B \subseteq \overline{A+B}$ or $\overline A + \overline B \supseteq \overline{A+B}$ ??

Comment: @GEdgar no, i can't

Comment: How about using the characterization of closure in terms of sequences?

Comment: (Brian's answer in the proposed duplicate answers this question, although suddenly I'm not too sure anymore)

Comment: @GEdgar I doubt if the OP knows what he is doing like he mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's not true.  [need one counter example for sum of two closed set need not be closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137431/need-one-counter-example-for-sum-of-two-closed-set-need-not-be-closed)

The above link provides an example of sets A and B which are closed such that A+B is not closed.  Using the above, we'd have that $\bar{A} = A$, and $\bar{B} = B$, but since $A +B$ is not closed, the proposition fails.

Whoops.  Beaten to the punch.

Comment: Ah, that should be the real duplicate. Not what I had proposed.

Comment: @amWhy: commenting is only possible when reputation is $\geq50$. (and thanks for the dup. link in the closure!)