# If A and B are compact than also A+B

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Suppose we have a topological vector space $X$ and $A, B\subset X$. We define A+B to be the set of the sums $a+b$ where $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. We should prove that also A+B is compact if A and B are compact. But the union of arbitrary compact sets isn't compact in generell. Thus: why is the statement wel true?

Comment: What do you know about $+\colon X\times X \to X$?

Comment: that this is continuous and the space is translation invariant

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function $F(x,y): X \times X \to X$ defined by $F(x,y)=x+y$ is continuous, and $A \times B$ is compact in $X \times Y$.

The image of a compact set under an continuous function is compact.

Comment: uniform continuity is rendundant

Comment: the compactness implies uniformly continuity? :-)

Comment: Ok, removed uniformity :) @17th LOL

Comment: why LOL? is this wrong?

Comment: @17th In topological vector spaces the addition is  uniformly continuous, so we get the u.c. for free. But you are right, by compactness $F$ should become u.c when restricted to $A \times B$. uniform continuity is not needed, and as posted redundant, I only mentioned it originally cause we get it for free...

Comment: Okay :-) thank you for help :-)

Comment: Is the Statement also true if we take bounded instead of compact?? Is every bounded closed set compact? Or only is several cases?

Comment: @17th To speak of boundedness you typically need a norm. Now, if the topology on $X$ is given by a norm, and $A,B$ are bounded, by the triangle inequality $A+B$ is also bounded.... More exactly, if $\|x\| \leq C_1$ for all $x \in A$ and $\|y \| \leq C_2$ for all $y \in B$, then $\|z\| \leq C_1+C_2$ for all $z \in A+B$.

Comment: @17th But this is not a good approach, as sum of closed sets is not necessarily closed. See for example: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124130/sum-of-two-closed-sets-in-mathbb-r-is-closed

Comment: Could we solve it without using the fact that: The image of a compact set under an continuous function is compact.