# Algebraic sum of closed sets that is not closed

Tags: real-analysis

In this discussion:
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/131987/114618
One of the posts argues that the sets
$E = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb R^2 : y \ge 1/x\text{ and }x > 0\}$ and $F = \{(x, y) \in\mathbb R^2 : y \ge -1/x\text{ and }x < 0\}$ are both closed, but that their algebraic sum 
$$E + F = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb R^2 : y > 0\}$$
is not closed.

My question is: why would $F$ be closed in the first place?
If I take the sequence $(x_n , y_n) = (1/n , n+1)$, with $n=1, 2, 3, ...$, this sequence would converge to a point on the y-axis (ie. where $x=0$), but that point would not be in $F$. Given that $F$ does not contain one of its limit points, how can we argue that it is closed?

Comment: Why? @martin-sleziak could you provide your input into this matter?

Comment: Missed a sign. It is correct.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for checking anyways :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there is no **point** on the axis that the sequence $(x_n , y_n) = (1/n , n+1)$ converges to. Your sequence approaches the axis, yes, but that is not enough for convergence - there is no **limit point** of that sequence.

If you lok at any sequence in the region $F$ that does converge to a point, then you will indeed find that the point is in $F$.

Comment: So, OldJohn does not think that $(0,+\infty)$ is a point in $\mathbb R^2$.  I agree with him.

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks! So long as I am not dealing with the Riemann sphere, I like to keep $\infty$ out of things :)

Comment: Thank you. Is this a proven result or is this still the subject of academic debate? Are the points $(0 , +{\infty})$, $(0 , -{\infty})$, $(+{\infty} , 0)$, $(-{\infty} , 0)$, $(+{\infty} , +{\infty})$ and $(-{\infty} , -{\infty})$ part of the set $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: Most people would not consider any of those points to be in $\mathbb{R}^2$. I certainly can't think of any textbook which would do so, so I wouldn't think it is the subject of academic debate.

Answer (score 0):

The $x$-coordinate of your sequence converges to $0$.  But the $y$-coordinate does not converge.

Answer (score 0):

$A=\{1+1,2+{1\over   2},3+{1\over 3},\dots\}$

$B=\{-1,-2,-3,\dots\}$

$A+B=\{1,{1\over 2},\dots\}$

Comment: But $A+B$ also contains $(1+1)+(-2)$, right?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers pointing out that the sequence $(n+1)$ does not converge, let me mention that
$$F=\{(x,y)\colon xy\le -1, x\le0\},$$
which shows that $F$ is closed, since $(x,y)\mapsto xy$ and $(x,y)\mapsto x$ are continuous.