# Minkowski sum: open/closed?

Tags: real-analysis

If two sets $A,B$ in $\mathbb{R^n}$ are closed. Will $A+B$ then be closed or open? In my head it makes sense if it is closed but I can't prove it on paper.

Comment: I hope [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124130/sum-of-two-closed-sets-in-mathbb-r-is-closed) will be helpful to you.

Comment: Just for the record: even if $A+B$ turned out to be closed: "not open" does not mean "closed" (that is: $A+B$ might be neither closed nor open). There is also no reason, why $A+\emptyset$ should be open, if $A$ is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A= \cup _{n\in \bf N, n\geq 2} \{n+1/n\}$, and $B= \cup _{n\in \bf N, n\geq 2} \{-n\}$

Then $(A+B ) \cap [0,1]= \{ 1/n, n>2\}$, hence $A+B$ is not closed.

Comment: But is it compact?

Comment: @k.dkhk $A$, $B$, and $A+B$ are each unbounded, and thus not compact. (For example, $100.01\in A$, $-100\in B$, and $(200.005)+(-100)=100.005\in A+B$.)

Comment: If A is $compact$ and B is closed, $A+B$ is closed. Indeed if $a_n+b_n$ converge to $l$, up to a subsequence we may assume that $a_n$ converge to $a$. Then $b_n$ converge to $l-a$; therefore $l-a\in B$ (as $B$ is closed) and $l=a+b\in A+B$