# Give a counterexample of $K_{1}$ and $K_{2}$ closed, but that $A$ is not closed.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness, examples-counterexamples

Take any $K_{1}$ and $K_{2}$ closed sets. Define $A = \{||x-y||: x \in K_{1}, y \in K_{2}\}$. I'm asked to prove (or give a counterexample) that $A$ is closed, in general.

A classmate came up with the following counterexample:

> Consider $K_{1},K_{2} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $K_{1} = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x\geq 1, y=0\}$, i.e, the horizontal axis from $1$ on and $K_{2} = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x\geq 1, y=1/x\}$. Clearly, both sets are closed. Notice that there are elements in $A$ that are arbitrarily close to $0$ but $0 \notin A$. Then, $A$ is not closed.

I could come up with some more examples, but all of them in the same spirit of the one above. I could also prove that if either $K_{1}$ or $K_{2}$ is compact, then $A$ is closed. So, a counterexample should rely on two unbounded sets, since I'm thinking about Euclidean spaces for the sake of simplicity.

In special, I was trying to find a counterexample in which $K_{1}$ and $K_{2}$ are subsets or the real numbers, but I had no success! Any ideas? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: The question already has an answer: [http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124130/sum-of-two-closed-sets-in-mathbb-r-is-closed](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/124130/290189)

Comment: $$K_1=\{1,2,3,4,5,\dots\}$$ $$K_2=\{1.1,2.01,3.001,4.0001,5.00001,\dots\}$$

Comment: Thanks everyone!! Nice example @bof!