# Sum of two closed subsets of positive reals is closed or not?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $A$ and $B$ be closed subsets of $[0, \infty)$ then is $A+B$ closed?, I know that the answer is negative when we have $\mathbb{R}$ instead of $[0, \infty)$, but every counterexample in that case exploits the fact that one of A or B can contain negative values.

Note: Using answers given below this can be easily generalised,

If $A$ and $B$ are closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ which are bounded below (or above) then $A+B$ is closed.

Comment: as background, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124130/sum-of-two-closed-sets-in-mathbb-r-is-closed) is the question about (not only non-negative) reals

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose we have $a_n+b_n\to x$ with $a_n\in A$, $b_n\in B$. Then all $a_n$ are in the compact interval $[0,x]$, hence there is a convergent subsequence $a_{n_k}\to a\in A$. Then $b_{n_k}\to x-a\in B$ and so $x=a+b\in A+B$.

Comment: Is there a typo. here, or am I missing something?  Say $A=B=[0,2]$ with $a_n=1+\frac1n$ and $ b_n=0+\frac1n$ and $a_n+b_n\to x=1$.  That does not mean all $a_n$ are in the (compact) interval $[0,x]=[0,1]$!?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner . You are right. It is not true that all $a_n$ must belong to $[0,x]$.... But $(a_n)_n$ must be a bounded sequence so it has a convergent sub-sequence.

Comment: Thank you very much @DanielWainfleet; that makes sense

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is closed. Suppose otherwise. That is, suppose that there are sequences $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of $A$ and $B$ respectively such that the sequence $(a_n+b_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to some $x\in\mathbb R\setminus(A+B)$. Then the sequence $(a_n+b_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is bounded and therefore both sequences $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ are bounded too. Take $K>0$ such that$$(\forall n\in\mathbb N):a_n,b_n\in[0,K].$$Then $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ are sequences of elements of $A\cap[0,K]$ and of $B\cap[0,K]$ respectively, which are *compact* sets. But the sum of two compact subsets of $\mathbb R$ is compact and therefore closed.

Comment: I think you meant "and $(b_n)$" when you wrote "and $(a_n)$", and did you mean $A+B$ when you wrote $A\cup B$?

Comment: Yes. I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer