# If $A$ and $B$ are compact, then so is $A+B$.

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, topological-vector-spaces, sumset

This is an exercise in Chapter 1 from Rudin's [*Functional Analysis*](http://books.google.com.hk/books/about/Functional_analysis.html?id=Sh_vAAAAMAAJ).

Prove the following:

> Let $X$ be a topological vector space. If $A$ and $B$ are compact subsets of $X$, so is $A+B$.

My guess: Let $\cup V_{\alpha}$ be an open covering of $A+B$, if we can somehow split each $V_{\alpha}$ into two parts \begin{equation}
V_{\alpha}=W_{\alpha}+U_{\alpha}
\end{equation} with \begin{equation}
\cup W_{\alpha}\supset A, \cup U_{\alpha}\supset B
\end{equation} then we can easily pass the compactness of $A$ and $B$ to $A+B$.

However, I cannot find such a way to split $V_{\alpha}$. I admit this is the only nontrivial part of this problem.

Any hint would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: The sum is a continuous operation. The image $A + B$ of the compact set $A \times B$ is therefore compact.

Comment: @AndréCaldas Thanks! Here is a related problem. Find an example to show that sum of closed sets may fail to be closed. Could you have a look at this?

Comment: @HuiYu Let $A$ be the graph of $1/x$, and $B$ the $y$-axis.

Comment: In $\Bbb R^2$ let $$H=\left\{\left\langle x,\frac1x\right\rangle:x>0\right\}$$ and $$K=\left\{\left\langle x,-\frac1x\right\rangle:x>0\right\}\;.$$ Then $H+K\supseteq\{\langle x,0\rangle:x>0\}$, so $\langle 0,0\rangle$ is a limit point of $H+K$ that is not in $H+K$.

Comment: @AlexBecker Thanks!

Comment: [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/60458/8271) Jonas Meyer answer

Comment: @AlexBecker: I always thought that $y$-axis was an open set. Is it clopen?

Comment: @Libertron It is definitely not open. It is closed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Posting André's comment for the sake of having an answer with positive score (to prevent future bumps):

The sum is a continuous operation. The image A+B of the compact set A×B is therefore compact.

Comment: Sorry, Austin... I should have posted a proper answer...

Comment: @AndréCaldas It's no problem. If you want to go ahead and do so (and receive the rep you deserve), I am happy to delete this one.

Comment: Thanks, Austin. But I guess I will wait for André for a few more days before I accept your answer.

Comment: @HuiYu Even if you accept this one and André posts, you can change your accepted answer.

Comment: Austin and @HuiYu, it is fine by me if you accept Austin's answer. I would just suggest that the role played by the product topology be more emphasized and maybe the notation could be enhanced... :-)